# HTML Image tag calls a function

Tags: html

The src is typically:

```
https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
```

I'm seeing this:

```
/merchantWeb/attachment_retrieve_image.action?&f=ece12848387b0a1e34c3c7e3414e5e4b
```

So the guid is passed to the web server which does a lookup on the backend and returns the image?  What technology does this?  Is the image renderable using the conventional srv value?

Comment: can you show us the code that you use to display the image?

Comment: <img id="cbx_defaultImage$0" name="cbx_defaultImage" src="/merchantWeb/attachment_retrieve_image.action?&amp;f=ece12848387b0a1e34c3c7e3414e5e4b" style="border: 1px dotted rgb(128, 128, 128); cursor: pointer; height: 200px; width: auto;" title="Zoom In" onload="Core.Document.resizeImage(this, 200, 200)" data-pin-nopin="true">

Comment: So that's what you see on the front end. Do you know the code generating that html?

Comment: Ah nope, hence the question.

Comment: Is it your website? and you don't know what  framework or language?

Comment: Hello @JasonJoslin No not my website. Framework and language unknown